# Calling a common method across multiple static classes?

Tags: c#, generics, static-methods

### A Quick Note

The code in this post is built on top of a in-house built `DirectX-11` engine which means it follows the strict pattern of:

```
Initialize
while (Running) {
    Update
    Render
}
```

However, do not let this deter you as the problem is not related to the `DirectX` code but instead `static` classes and methods.

---

### Overview

I have a class called `RenderObject` which contains a method called `Initialize`. This method is responsible for building the object's mesh, assigning textures, shaders, and more.

```
public class RenderObject {
    public virtual void Initialize() { }
}
```

I also have a few `static` classes that hold reusable assets such as common textures, shaders, models, and meshes. This way I don't have to reload them later. All of these `static` classes also contain a method called `Initialize` which is responsible for creating these reusable assets. For this question I will limit this to just the `Textures` class.

```
public static class Textures {
    public static Texture2D Dirt { get; private set; }
    public static Texture2D Grass { get; private set; }
    public static void Initialize() {
        Dirt = new Texture2D(...);
        Grass = new Texture2D(...);
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a class called `LoadingSystem` which is responsible for loading reusable assets and initializing objects. I initialize this class inside of the `Initialize` method of my engine, and then call the class' `Update` method in the `Update` method of the engine respectively. The `LoadingSystem`'s `Update` method is responsible for loading and initializing objects using a `Queue` which is useful for supplying smooth visual feedback.

```
 public class LoadingSystem {
     public bool Loading { get; private set; } = true;
     private Queue<RenderObject> objectsToRender;
     public void AddForLoad(RenderObject obj) => objectsToRender.Enqueue(obj);
     public void Update() {
         if (objectsToRender.Count > 0) {
             RenderObject obj = objectsToLoad.Dequeue();
             obj.Initialize();
         } else Loading = false;
     }
 }
```

---

### The Problem

I would like to call the method `Initialize` on these `static` classes with the same process used for the `RenderObject` queue. Currently I'm forced to do:

```
CurrentMessage = "Loading Textures";
Render();
Present();
Textures.Initialize();
Progress = ++objectsLoaded / objectsToLoad;
CurrentMessage = "Loading Shaders";
Render();
Present();
Shaders.Initialize();
Progress = ++objectsLoaded / objectsToLoad;
CurrentMessage = "Loading Models";
Render();
Present();
Models.Initialize();
Progress = ++objectsLoaded / objectsToLoad;
```

I've slimmed it down to a method that handles the repetitive setting of the message, and calls to `Render` and `Present` but this is still tedious and it should go through the `Update` method once per object to remain consistent with the rest of the code.

---

### My Thoughts

I understand that a `static` class cannot inherit from a `class` or implement an `interface` so I am wondering if there is a way to provide a `static` class and call its `Initialize` method in a similar manner; even if this means creating a separate method to accomplish it.

I have currently considered two options:

- Load static classes individually.
- Convert static classes to instance classes and call them with the queue.

The problem with the first option is that I have 12 `static` classes and would have to update progress and feedback messages, raise events, and re-render the scene for each one.

The problem with the second option is that these `static` classes only contain `static` properties and thus by definition should be `static` as there is no need to ever inherit from them or create an instance of them.

---

### The Question

Is there a way to call a common method across multiple static classes?

- Perhaps a way to call the method if it exists with generic types like `object` or `T`?
- Perhaps the `dynamic` type may work (though you can't create an instance of `static` classes)?

Comment: When you say "Load static classes individually" what do you mean? You cannot have an instance of a `static` class. Do you have 12 different static types, or 12 instances of the same type?

Comment: It's also not clear to me what problem you're trying to solve. In what way is your current code not working?

Comment: @RufusL I know that I can't create instances, and when I say *load static classes individually* it means by calling `Textures.Initialize()` then `Models.Initialize()` and so on and so forth.

Comment: Is `Textures` a collection class (since the name is plural)?

Comment: @RufusL My code works fine as it currently sits, but I have described my concern quite thoroughly, I wish to call a common method across several `static` classes.

Comment: Oh, wow, that makes sense. That comment ^ was so clear and easy to understand. You should edit you question and replace everything with that!

Comment: `Textures` contains a laundry list of static `Texture2D` objects representing common textures used in my application.

Comment: @RufusL If I were to replace my entire post with that single comment it would probably be deleted. :D

Comment: Have you considered using the Singleton pattern rather than statics? The advantage from your use case's perspective is that Singletons can implement an interface with this method signature or even inherit from a common abstract base class.

Comment: @AdamG That is a very good suggestion! If you wouldn't mind writing up a brief answer on it I will mark it as accepted. That is definitely a better approach than full `static` classes. I've already located a detailed article on implementation in various scenarios but an overview for future readers would be nice to have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have currently considered two options:
>
> - Load static classes individually.
> - Convert static classes to instance classes and call them with the queue.

A third compromise approach relates to your second idea above, but uses a design pattern known as the Singleton Pattern. Like static classes, there can only be one of them in your process and everyone gets that same thing, however unlike static classes, Singletons can implement interfaces or even descend from other classes.

For this example, I will use the interface approach.

```
public interface IInitializable
{
    void Initialize();
}
```

All the interface does is to enforce that its implementer has an Initialize method.

My next step is to create a Singleton class. There are a couple of rules to implement the Singleton pattern. Your class must be sealed. Its constructor must be private. It must have a static method or property to return the single instance. That method/property must be threadsafe.

I have used Lazy to do the heavy lifting for me

```
public sealed class Foo : IInitializable
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // Initialize my foo
    }

    private Foo()
    {
    }

    private static Lazy<Foo> fooLazy = new Lazy<Foo>(() => new Foo());

    public static Foo Instance => fooLazy.Value;
}
```

There are some minor differences to what you were doing with static classes. If Foo was a static class, you would call `Foo.Initialize();` As it is Singleton, you would call `Foo.Instance.Initialize();`

Any other methods or properties would most likely be non-static.

Pulling it all together, you could write code like this. Your queue does not need to know about the classes it holds. You don't actually care. You only want to know that it has the Initialize() method

```
   public class YourClass
    {
        private Queue<IInitializable> objectsToLoad = new Queue<IInitializable>();

        public void Enqueue(IInitializable obj)
        {
            this.objectsToLoad.Enqueue(obj);
        }

        public void LoadOrUpdate()
        {
            // Update Method
            if (objectsToLoad.Count > 0)
            {
                IInitializable obj = objectsToLoad.Dequeue();
                obj.Initialize();
            }
            else
            {
                // Loading complete.
            }
        }
    }
```

This class could then be used like this

```
    YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
    yourClass.Enqueue(Foo.Instance);
    yourClass.LoadOrUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I hope there is a much better and more detailed answer than this; I've come up with a basic solution. I created a separate `Queue<Type>` where I add the `static` classes. I then call their `Initialize` method with the following:

```
Type t = typesToInit.Dequeue();
t.GetMethod("Initialize").Invoke(null, new object[] { 0 });
```

This works well and is rather clean, but I can't help but wonder if there is a better way to do this?